# Android duplicate dependencies error - Annotation

Tags: annotations, jackson, duplicates, converters

when I was building my projecti I get some errors like this

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonAnnotation.class

How can I resolve this problem?